# Exporting A4 report creates Letter or A3 paper size when exporting to MS Word

Tags: ms-word, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a simple report created in BIDS 2008 and deployed to a SSRS 2008 server. It has the following report properties:

- page unit: Centimeters
- page size:

  - Orientasion: Landscape
  - paper sise: A4
  - width : 29,7cm
  - Height: 21cm
- all margins are 2,5cm

Showing and printing this report works fine on a A4 paper. Exporting to different formats works great as well, except the format I made the report for. The Word files end up with an *Letter* paper size or A3 size.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the body width plus 5 cm (left margin plus right margin) was interpreted as being too big for A4 and so was upgraded to the next size larger (A3.)  I've seen this sort of thing happen with formatting (the infamous "blank" pages in the report when viewing in print layout or exported layout) when the paper size is set to be smaller than the right margin plus the left margin plus the body width.  Seems a lot of people are not even aware that the body of the report has its own sizing.  Hope this helps someone out there.